# What is the airplane in this video?

Tags: aircraft-identification

What is the airplane in this video?

(Video is intentionally set to start at 1:27; that is shortly before the first appearance of the airplane in the video.  After 1:50 there are no clear views of the exterior of the airplane, and only extremely limited views of the interior, so there is little need to watch beyond that point, unless you are into the music.  At 2:12-2:15 there is a brief low-resolution shot that includes a good portion of the control panel; nothing of significance after that.)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [Pacific Aerospace P-750 XSTOL](https://www.utilityaircraft.com/index.html)

[image]